# Query through database and pullout user by user id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

I have table of cities, birthday, and users.
Now, what I am trying to do is to query through database and filter range of ages and city of living (out of a list of cities in the selected region - that is why I am checking if count($city[]))>=1), and finely pull out the name of the user based on uid / entety_id. 
First I am checking if the user match the range of age, and then if he lives in one of the cities from the selected list.
If no city was selected, I want to filter only the range of ages.

I don't know what is the problem but as far as I notice,
there is this loop, that I have notice that does not execute at all:

```
for ($d = 1; $d < (count($the_resaults_array)); $d++)
```

this is the code:

```
function toodate_query_db($loest_age, $highest_age, $city){
    $sql_user_name = '';

    if((count($city[0]))>=1){
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($city); $i++) {
            $city_item_for_check = $city[$i];

            $sql = "SELECT field_data_field_birth_date.entity_id
                        FROM field_data_field_birth_date, field_data_field_city
                        WHERE(
                        (field_birth_date_value >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -{$highest_age} YEAR))
                        AND 
                        (field_birth_date_value <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -{$loest_age} YEAR))
                        AND 
                        (field_city_tid = {$city_item_for_check})
                        AND
                        (field_data_field_birth_date.entity_id = field_data_field_city.entity_id))";
            if(db_query($sql)->fetchColumn()){
            $the_resaults_array[$i] = db_query($sql)->fetchAll();
            }
        }

        for ($d = 1; $d < (count($the_resaults_array)); $d++) {

            $user_id = $the_resaults_array[$d];

            $sql_user_name .= '<p><strong>'.
            db_query("SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE uid = {$user_id}")->fetchColumn()
            .'</p></strong>';           
        }
    } else{
        $sql = "SELECT field_data_field_birth_date.entity_id
            FROM field_data_field_birth_date 
            WHERE
                field_birth_date_value >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -{$highest_age} YEAR) 
                AND field_birth_date_value <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -{$loest_age} YEAR)";


        foreach (db_query($sql) as $result) {
            $entity_id = $result->entity_id;

            $sql_user_id = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {profile} WHERE pid = {$entity_id}")->fetchColumn();

            $sql_user_name .= '<p><strong>'.
            db_query("SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE uid = {$sql_user_id}")->fetchColumn()
            .'</p></strong>';

        }}

        return $sql_user_name;
}
```

Comment: Haven't verified your above codes, but you might want some approaches different from this, like using JOIN for sql server, as database run queries in RAM faster then you using PHP to launch separated queries.

Comment: Use left or INNER joins. It works faster and it is easier:) Here is a link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Is there a reason why are you not using views module